# SQL Group By and return pairs from list

Tags: sql, group-by, distinct

Sorry if the title doesn't match this content.

I currently have a database that has a list of schedules and the places it travels through.

```
HeaderId, LocationOrdinal, Location
1,0,A
1,1,B
1,2,C
1,3,D
1,4,E

2,0,A
2,1,B
2,2,F
2,3,G
```

I would like to have them grouped by HeaderId, have the locations next to each other and then distinct.

```
Desired Output
A,B
B,C
C,D
D,E
B,F
F,G
```

Note that A,B is only in there once.

I currently get all the values in the table and do it via C#, but it's very slow.

SELECT HeaderId, Location FROM [dbo].[sched_timings] ORDER BY HeaderId, LocationOrdinal

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses `join`:

```
select distinct st.Location, stnext.Location
from sched_timings st join
     sched_timings stnext
     on stnext.HeaderId = st.HeaderId and
        stnext.LocationOrdinal = st.LocationOrdinal + 1;
```

Another method uses `lead()`:

```
select distinct location, next_location
from (select st.*, 
             lead(location) over (partition by HeaderId order by LocationOrdinal) as next_location
      from sched_timings st
     ) st
where next_location is not null;
```

Comment: What does lead do please?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15